# Page loading scrolled to bottom

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Has anyone had the issue where some versions IE7 and 9beta will load a page scrolled to the bottom? This only happens when clicking from the main nav, not directly inputting the url. [Here's an example](http://bit.ly/e7BRrU)

How would I add a scrollTop function to each main nav link via jQuery? Would that be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: That *is* weird.  It happens for me when putting the url directly in IE7.

Comment: @Stephen fun isn't it? should have been a salesman!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround, you could add this to each page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).scrollTop(0);
});
```

You wouldn't be able to add this to the links, as the script needs to run after the page load.  This also feels hacky without knowing what is causing the problem, but with IE, I would rather hack sometimes than know...

Comment: @Jeff B - Thats where I'm at right now. Ive removed each script and added them back in to try and narrow it down but to no avail, its very quirky. I'm afraid if it is in fact caused by either the jQTools tabs, the adspeed ad serving code or by the google tracking code (saw instances caused by adsense) there's not much I can do but hack. No other browser exhibits this. I don't like IE much.

Comment: @Jeff B - Unfortunately the above hack didn't seem to do anything. Am I going to have to add anchors to each page and change the main nav to point to those? this sucks.

Comment: Its possible the scroll occurs as a result of another script.  In that case, it may fire after yours.

Comment: Time to go through a page and remove each script, add them back in one by one. It must be something that triggers a bug in IE in one of them, although it just started happening.

Comment: @Jeff B - I played with the above code and got it to work, although its still a nasty little hack <!--[if IE 7 | IE 9 ]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
   });
  </script>
 <![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

The hack was well, a hack. If anyone else has this issue it has to do with the site loading in compatability mode. We had a guy in the office who's IE was loading every page in compatability mode and every site he went to was doing this, he mentioned this and I took a look at our site. On some machines, the ones that exhibited this issue they were in fact loading in compatability mode, turning it off resolved the issue. Thanks Microsoft!